# Error al mostrar datos de una consulta a un select laravel

Tags: laravel

Aquí esta mi consulta laravel en una funcion :

```
 $anos_consulta =\DB::table('organizador_tareas')
            ->join('anos_trabajo','anos_trabajo.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.ano')
            ->select('anos_trabajo.anos_trabajo')
            ->get();

//         dd($anos);


        return \View::make('empleado_inicio',compact('paises','nivel_academico'
            ,'titulo_obtenido','departamento_honduras','tipo_contratacion','dep_icf','bancos','anos_consulta'));
    }
```

aqui esta el select de laravel donde lo quiero mostrar el problema es que si le agrego un foreach, si me los muestra pero en select diferentes y no en uno solo como una lista:

```
              <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('ano', 'Ano:', ['class' => 
                  'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                  <div class="col-lg-10">

                 {!!Form::select('ano',$anos_consulta,['required'=>'required'])!!}

                             </div>
                         </div>
```

Este es el error que me tira:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-empleados_pestañas.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-empleados_pestañas.blade.php)

Comment: Que contiene esa variable haciendole dd($anos_consulta) ???

Comment: contiene el nombre de todos los años el problema es que cuando lo quiero mostrar en un select laravel me muestra ese error pero si le pongo un ciclo foreach me muestra los datos pero cada dato en un select diferente y no en uno solo como una lista

Comment: El error que te esta mostrando esta estrechamente vinculado con el tipo de datos que es $anos_consulta, has lo que te pedi pon una muestra de lo que viene en esa variable con un dd y ponlo en tu pregunta para hacernos a la idea mejor

Comment: ya lo pude resolver en vez de colocarle  ->get( );  le coloque                       
   ->pluck('anos_trabajo','anos_trabajo'); en la consulta